# Pandas: how to recover data values after stacking columns

Tags: python, database, pandas

I have a dataframe comprising of 3 columns, all of which contain numerical values. I indexed the dataframe using first column, and stacked the resulting dataframe.

```
df.columns = ['Timestamp','X','Y']
df = df.set_index('Timestamp')
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df.stack())
```

Now, I want to plot the numerical values. But it seems that the identity of numerical values is lost. When I give the following command

```
plt.plot(df_1);plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Is `unstack` what you're looking for? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html

Comment: If unstack is the opposite of stack, then no I'm not looking for unstack. I stacked the dataframe just because I could have a single sequence of numbers that alternates between entries from X and Y column.

Comment: There's probably a better way to do what you want. You should post your input and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to plot `X` and `Y` values on a time series, you don't need `stack()`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# sample data
dates = pd.date_range('2016','2017',freq='M')
data = {'X': np.random.random(size=len(dates)), 
        'Y':np.random.random(size=len(dates))}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dates)
df.index = df.index.rename('timestamp')

                   X         Y
timestamp                     
2016-01-31  0.006331  0.757617
2016-02-29  0.802825  0.649958
2016-03-31  0.574478  0.952331
2016-04-30  0.354422  0.197825
2016-05-31  0.619783  0.618860
2016-06-30  0.889533  0.120012
2016-07-31  0.216237  0.838509
2016-08-31  0.610442  0.921350
2016-09-30  0.393746  0.285434
2016-10-31  0.409300  0.722278
2016-11-30  0.607809  0.176804
2016-12-31  0.636723  0.213197
```

Now just use `plot()`:

```
df.plot()
```

[image: time series plot]

Answer (score 0):

Just use `df_1.plot()` which I think can solve your problem.